# Error: Missing redirect_uri parameter. ( website login with facebook)

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

> stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Missing
>   redirect_uri parameter. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 191 ) )

I get this message when I send access_token to graph.facebook.com/oauth/me

```
if($result){
        print_r(get_data($result));
    }

function get_data($token){
    $ku = curl_init();
    $query = "access_token=".$token;

    curl_setopt($ku, CURLOPT_URL, "graph.facebook.com/oauth/me?".$query);
    curl_setopt($ku, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ku);

    return json_decode($result);    
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have to get the data about the user who logs in to my site, but I get "Missing redirect_uri parameter".

Answer (score 1):

The API endpoint to get basic user information is `graph.facebook.com/me`, not `graph.facebook.com/oauth/me`. You should add "https" too: `https://graph.facebook.com/me`.